# Application not displaying contacts

Tags: android, android-emulator

I had created an application that showed me all the columns of the content provider "content://contacts/people". One of the fields was times_contacted. So, i made an application to show the display name and the times_contacted. I know about ContactContract. But I want to know whay the fallowing code is not displaying the account details. The application works fine on the JellyBean emulator but on my phone which runs on Ice Cream Sandwich, the application shows a blank activity whereas on emulator shows the contact list. Another thing I want to know that while using CursorLoader how I can iterate through the query results as I was not able to get any cursor reference. Am i supposed to use ContentResolver separatly ?
Here is the code for the my app. I have included the READ_CONTACT permission.

```
package legacy_systems.contactsdisplay;

import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.app.LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks;
import android.content.CursorLoader;
import android.content.Loader;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.database.Cursor;
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity implements LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>{
    SimpleCursorAdapter madapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        madapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, 
                                           android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2,
                                           null,
                                           new String[]{"display_name","times_contacted" },
                                           new int[]{android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2},0);
        setListAdapter(madapter);

        getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Done", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
        Uri baseUri = Uri.parse("content://contacts/people");
        return new CursorLoader(this, baseUri,null,null,null,null);
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
    }
    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> arg0, Cursor arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        madapter.swapCursor(arg1);
    }



    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        madapter.swapCursor(null);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, on iterating over the cursor obtained from querying contact content provider, I learnt that the cursor was empty. it didn't had any rows in it. so, no chance of being displayed.